# Python beautifulSoup: create and combine lists and remove redundancies like \n

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, removing-whitespace

How can I combine the full lists into a dataframe.  When I print it seems to only print the first record and it also includes \n and other redundancies like ' etc.

```
    import requests
    from requests_html import HTML, HTMLSession
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    import csv
    import json

    url = 'https://lehighsports.com/sports/mens-soccer/schedule/2018'
    lehigh = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(lehigh,'lxml')

    for opp in soup.find_all('div',class_="sidearm-schedule-game-opponent-text"):
        opp_list = []
        opp_list.append(opp.text)
     #   print(opp_list)

    for conf in soup.find_all('div',class_="sidearm-schedule-game-conference-conference"):
        conf_list = []
        conf_list.append(conf.text)
    #    print(conf_list)

    dict = {'opponent':[opp_list],'conference':[conf_list]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
    print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `opp_list` and `conf_list` in every iteration to `[]` - initialize them only once. Alson, you don't have to put brackets in dictionary creation `{'opponent':opp_list,'conference':conf_list}`

To remove whitespace, you can use `.get_text()` method with `strip=True` and `separator=` parameters.

For example:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://lehighsports.com/sports/mens-soccer/schedule/2018'
lehigh = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(lehigh,'lxml')

opp_list = []
for opp in soup.find_all('div',class_="sidearm-schedule-game-opponent-text"):
    opp_list.append(opp.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))

conf_list = []
for conf in soup.find_all('div',class_="sidearm-schedule-game-conference-conference"):
    conf_list.append(conf.get_text(strip=True))

dict = {'opponent':opp_list,'conference':conf_list}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                         opponent       conference
0                        at UConn                 
1                       vs Drexel                 
2            at George Washington                 
3                   at St. John's                 
4                   vs Binghamton                 
5                        at Rider                 
6                         vs Penn                 
7                         at Army  Patriot League*
8                      vs Cornell                 
9                     at Boston U  Patriot League*
10                 vs #20 Colgate  Patriot League*
11                        vs Navy  Patriot League*
12                   at Lafayette  Patriot League*
13                   at Dartmouth                 
14                    vs American  Patriot League*
15                    at Bucknell  Patriot League*
16                at Loyola (Md.)  Patriot League*
17     vs Holy Cross Senior Night  Patriot League*
18  vs No. 3 Colgate (Semifinals)
```